# HTML&CSS center items

Tags: html, css

I have [this box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plpjq.png) that I want to display on a web page through HTML&CSS.
But I can't manage to place the white boxes inside the blue one. Any help is appreciated.
The CSS I put is just so I can see the borders of the elements.
[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI841.png)

```
<div class="table">
<h1 class = "title">Data Manipulation Language</h1>
    <ul class="content">
        
        <li class = "update">
            <p>UPDATE</p>
            <p> UPDATE MyTable</p>
            <p>SET col1 = 56</p>
            <p>WHERE col2 = 'something';</p>
        </li>
        
        <li class="insert" >
            <p>INSERT<p>
            <p>INSERT INTO MyTable(col1, col 2)</p>
            <p>VALUES ('value1', 'value2');</p>
            <p></p>
        </li>
        
        <li class="delete">     
            <p>DELETE</p>
            <p>DELETE FROM MyTable</p>
            <p>WHERE col1 = 'something';</p>
            <p></p> 
        </li>
        
        <li class="select">     
            <p>SELECT</p>
            <p>SELECT col1, col2</p>
            <p>FROM MyTable;</p>
            <p></p>
        </li>
    
    </ul>
    
</div>
```

```
.update/.delete/.insert/.select(the classes of the white boxes) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 5px;
    padding:10px;
    border: 6px solid #FF0004;
    border-width: 5;
}
```

Comment: Your css selector is invalid

Comment: Fine-tune CSS and try with the text-align center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `float:left` which is breaking the flow of your HTML element. For the layout creation of your application you can use latest layout technique like: **flex or Grid** and then for the expected style you can write css code.

You can align the list item as per the expected result by simply adding below code.

```
//this will set the layout as flex for each child element inside this class containing element
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

//taking 40% width for each list items that will break your layout in two column
.update, .delete, .insert, .select {
   width: 40%;
}
```

Full modified code is available below

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.update, .delete, .insert, .select {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    left: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding:10px;
    border: 6px solid #FF0004;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/trsldt0me90jzs8/resume.css"/>
<title></title> 
</head>
<body><div class="table">
<h1 class = "title">Data Manipulation Language</h1>
    <ul class="content">
        
        <li class = "update">
            <p>UPDATE</p>
            <p> UPDATE MyTable</p>
            <p>SET col1 = 56</p>
            <p>WHERE col2 = 'something';</p>
        </li>
        
        <li class="insert" >
            <p>INSERT<p>
            <p>INSERT INTO MyTable(col1, col 2)</p>
            <p>VALUES ('value1', 'value2');</p>
            <p></p>
        </li>
        
        <li class="delete">     
            <p>DELETE</p>
            <p>DELETE FROM MyTable</p>
            <p>WHERE col1 = 'something';</p>
            <p></p> 
        </li>
        
        <li class="select">     
            <p>SELECT</p>
            <p>SELECT col1, col2</p>
            <p>FROM MyTable;</p>
            <p></p>
        </li>
    
    </ul>
    
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added paddings, background color, basic stylings in main wrapper and used `grid` in inner items.

```css
.table {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em;
  list-style: none;
}

.content li {
  background: white;
  padding: 0.7em;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}

.content li p:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<h1 class = "title">Data Manipulation Language</h1>
    <ul class="content">
        
        <li class = "update">
            <p>UPDATE</p>
            <p> UPDATE MyTable</p>
            <p>SET col1 = 56</p>
            <p>WHERE col2 = 'something';</p>
        </li>
        
        <li class="insert" >
            <p>INSERT<p>
            <p>INSERT INTO MyTable(col1, col 2)</p>
            <p>VALUES ('value1', 'value2');</p>
            <p></p>
        </li>
        
        <li class="delete">     
            <p>DELETE</p>
            <p>DELETE FROM MyTable</p>
            <p>WHERE col1 = 'something';</p>
            <p></p> 
        </li>
        
        <li class="select">     
            <p>SELECT</p>
            <p>SELECT col1, col2</p>
            <p>FROM MyTable;</p>
            <p></p>
        </li>
    
    </ul>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the TABLE for forms or like this situation. 
Using TABLE's gives you easier to align and apply styles.
Just change a few lines of your code with my code and add the CSS.
**YOU WILL GET THE EXACT RESULT** as this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI841.png) you mentioned.

```css
table {
  background-color: #004aab;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-spacing: 8px;
 } 
td {
  padding: 10px;
 }
h1 {
  text-align: center;
 }
.header {
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
 }
.row1 td, .row2 td{
  background-color: white;
 }
.row1 td:nth-child(1) h3, .row1 td:nth-child(2) h3 {
  text-align: center;
 }
.row2 td:nth-child(1) h3, .row2 td:nth-child(2) h3 {
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="header">
    <th colspan=2>Data Manipulation Language</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row1">
    <td>
      <h3>UPDATE</h3>
      <p>UPDATE MyTable</p>
      <p>WHERE col2 = 'something';</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h3>INSERT</h3>
      <p>INSERT INTO MyTable(col1, col 2)</p>
      <p>VALUES ('value1', 'value2');</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
    <td>
      <h3>DELETE</h3>
      <p>DELETE FROM MyTable</p>
      <p>WHERE col1 = 'something';</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h3>SELECT</h3>
      <p>SELECT col1, col2</p>
      <p>FROM MyTable;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```